# Can't turn on Dark Theme in Google search when signed in

Tags: google-chrome, themes

When I sign out of my account in Google chrome and then do any search, I get an option in settings to change the appearance of the search window as shown in image below:

Signed out: [image]

But when I sign into my account and do any search, even though my Windows 10 and Google Chrome are in Dark mode, Google search window opens up in Light mode, and the option to switch it to Dark mode disappears from the settings dropdown:

Signed in: [image]

Where do I find the setting to turn on Dark mode (Dark theme) for Google search? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't this Google Support [article](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/10633314?hl=en) work? For me it works : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VdzS.jpg. Are you on Windows? Which versions for Windows and Chrome?

Comment: @harrymc I am sure thats it, put your comment in an answer to get those bounty points :)

Comment: @harrymc No sadly the article doesn't help :-( . On my main google account I have this: https://imgur.com/a/9GsHHKo
NB: It works perfectly fine on secondary accounts or even when I'm not connected at all. It even works fine on google support pages and uses dark mode (browser is in dark mode), but for google nothing seems to do the trick…

Comment: It works for me, still... Are you on Windows? Which versions for Windows and Chrome?

Comment: @harrymc I'm personally using Safari on macOS but the issue also occurs in other browsers and on iOS (OP having the issue on a windows 10 device). It's not that the menu to toggle dark mode is never there, it's not there when logged in on some accounts

Comment: @Marcio: When you are in [Google.com](https://www.google.com/), click on "Settings" at the bottom-right. Do you have an option for "Dark theme"? If not, click on "Search Settings > Appearance", do you now have an option for "Turn Dark theme on or off"?

Comment: @Marcio: Could you try updating Chrome? For me updating to v95.0.4638.54 fixed it. FYI, I am on Windows 10 v21H1 (Experience Pack v120.2212.3920.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dark Theme in Google Search is a relatively new option.
If it's not available for you, check that you have the latest software.

The Google Support article
[Search in Dark theme on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/10633314?hl=en)
says:

> You can change your preferred theme for Search by updating your Search
> settings.
>
> 1. On your computer, do a search on google.com.
> 2. If you want the same Search settings across browsers, sign in to your Google Account. At the top right, click Sign in.
>
>    - If you find your profile picture or initial, you’re already signed in.
> 3. At the top right, click Settings [image] and then Search settings.
> 4. On the left, click Appearance.
> 5. Choose Device default, Dark, or Light.
>
>    - Device default: Automatically match the color scheme of your current device
>    - Dark: Light text on a dark background
>    - Light: Dark text on a light background
>
> - At the bottom, click Save.
>
> Tip: To quickly switch between themes, click Settings  and then Dark
> theme: On or Dark theme: Off.

This is what this should look like:

[image]

Comment: Updating Chrome to v95.0.4638.54 seems to have fixed the issue. Now I can see the option to choose between themes. Thank you! :)